# play framework - run in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: playframework-2.0, ubuntu-11.10

how to correctly run play framework in ubuntu 11.10? i mean, i can run the sample app (helloworld) on terminal, but when i tried to open localhost:9001 (i run it at port 9001) on browser, i got "Connection was reset" response.
I tried opening localhost:9001/helloworld, i got this
[image]

Then, i tried opening localhost:9001/hello, i got "Connection was reset" again.
the reason i run it at port 9001 was because i have php-fpm running.

additional info: i have nginx and apache2 running. i stopped them, it still didn't work

Comment: Try to run it on some other port(s) (higher than 8000) maybe there is some other service working at 9001 too.

Answer (score 2):

For the initial issue, the problem is with your request path.  Looking at the routes, you don't have /helloworld mapped to anything.